# How to pass input data between 2 pages in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I've been learning react and trying to get a user input from one page to another. I've tried some different things already like refs and props and redux but I just can't figure it out. My goal is that when data is inserted to the text box and submit is clicked that I could show a list of these entries on the second page.

This is the page for input

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class New extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert(this.state.value + ' successfully created');
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label for="tournyName">Tournament name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tournyName" value= {this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create tournament</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default New;
```

Goal is to have user inputs in this list

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Tournaments extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h2>List of tournaments:</h2><br></br>
      <ul>
        <li>User created tournament name here</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Tournaments;
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: There are no "pages" in React.  You can either set the data as a prop and pass it down my instantiating 'Tournaments' in the 'New' component, or you can use Redux.

Answer (score -1):

Simple.Pass the data as array from the component where submit action is called and have a const  to iterate the map in the component where you want to render the Data.